# How to handle request json data in flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, flask

I would like to send json formatted data from my html page to a url on the click of a button, but currently the data is not getting updated to the url. I've included here a small subset of the data i'm trying to post. The GET method works fine for posting initial output to the url. The result of the ajax request is the alerted error output. How can I use POST to successfully update the output to the url?

The html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-success btn-space" id ="commitButton" name="commitButton" value="enter">Commit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('commitButton').onclick = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/processjson",
            type:'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": {"schema": {"fields":[{"name":"index","type":"integer"},{"name":"OB_TIME","type":"datetime"},{"name":"LATITUDE","type":"number"},{"name":"LONGITUDE","type":"number"}]}, "data": [{"index":0,"OB_TIME":"2015-09-03T00:00:00.000Z","LATITUDE":21.9,"LONGITUDE":-152.0}]},
            "contentType": "application/json",
             success: function(result) {
                            alert('ok');
                        },
             error: function(result) {
                            alert('error');
                        }
        })
    };

</script>
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/processjson', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def processjson():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify({'result':'Test'})

    # getting the table data when the commit button is pressed
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # gets jsonified data and convert it to a python data structure (dictionaries)
        data = request.get_json()
        fields = data['schema']['fields']
        tableData = data['schema']['data']
        return jsonify({'result':'Success!','tableData' : tableData})
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the json data inside the request body.
You can access the request body with `request.form.get('data')` to get a json string. This can be load to a dict using `json.load(json_str)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've changed my python code to request the data as you suggested (data = request.form.get('data')), but what should I change within the javascript? Is the request body the button? If you could provide an example that would be great. My eventual aim is to use this method to update data within a jquery datatable, but I thought getting a basic POST method to a url working would be a good first step. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`request.get_json()` parse form data as json, but this would work if you are submitting as form data. Looking at the JS snippet, it looks like you are not submitting it as form data (you are making an ajax call), so your data will be available in the property `request.json`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this : request.json